# change of format when transferring string from C# to Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I have a problem when I want transfer data from dataGridView in C# to Excel.

My data was "84853435455002" and when I saved in Excel I see this format "8.675675E2".

I want to save my data completely and not have "E" in my data .. 
what must I do to solve this .

Comment: What do you use to export data into excel?

Comment: @RoBy Shouldn't it be *"import into"*, and *"export from"*?

Comment: By transferring, do you mean Copy & Paste? Because then this question does most likely not belong on Stack Overflow, as it's an Excel-specific problem. I suspect that you can fix this by changing the cell format in Excel; either from numeric to text, or modify the number format string.

Comment: Nothing happened to your 'saved' data. Just format the column in excel. If you are generating excel from code, the formatting can be set from code. share your code snippet + the library you are using in that case

Answer (score 2):

You need to format your cells in Excel to Number and set any decimal places to 0 if you do not want decimal too. By default the Excel cell format is general which converts your input this way.

Answer (score 1):

u have to tell excel to read the cell as text. Or add some special character to numbers, so excel will read it as text. eg. " '84853435455002 " (put single quote in front of number)